# Change log formatter while hosting ASP.NET application in Docker

Tags: c#, docker

All console logs are being formatted with [SimpleConsoleFormatter](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/SimpleConsoleFormatter.cs) (until this setting is overridden) and the default output when running the ASP.NET app on Kestrel looks like following:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7007
```

But when I am using Docker to host my app - it looks like the [JsonConsoleFormatter](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/JsonConsoleFormatter.cs) is being used instead. It's just my guess... But anyway, the output now looks like following:

```
docker-webapi-1       | {"EventId":14,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Now listening on: https://[::]:443","State":{"Message":"Now listening on: https://[::]:443","address":"https://[::]:443","{OriginalFormat}":"Now listening on: {address}"}}
```

How can I make the Docker outputs look the same when I am just using Kestrel? Thanks.

What I want to achieve when using Docker:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://[::]:443
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aspnet docker images set the environment variable `Logging__Console__FormatterName` to `json` because Microsoft think that most people that run .NET code in Docker containers prefer that format.

To get it back to Simple formatting, you need to set the environment variable to `Simple` by adding

```
ENV Logging__Console__FormatterName=Simple
```

somewhere in your Dockerfile.

There's an open issue on Github about the change: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/3274